# How to diagnose “Invalid block type ..” error?

Tags: layout, blocks, error, exception

Not sure what's wrong with this, have been googling around but cannot find a solution, hopefully someone can help me here.

> exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Invalid block type: Mage_Catalog_Block_Layer' in app/Mage.php:563
>   Stack trace:
>   #0 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(469): Mage::throwException('Invalid block t...')
>   #1 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(411): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_getBlockInstance('catalog/layer', Array)
>   #2 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(446): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('catalog/layer', 'catalog.leftnav')
>   #3 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(238): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->addBlock('catalog/layer', 'catalog.leftnav')
>   #4 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(204): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateBlock(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Mod    el_Layout_Element))
>   #5 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(209): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
>   #6 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(345): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks()
>   #7 app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/controllers/CategoryController.php(146): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()
>   #8 app/code/local/Xprime/Category/controllers/CategoryController.php(75): Mage_Catalog_CategoryController->viewAction()
>   #9 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(420): Xprime_Category_CategoryController->viewAction()
>   #10 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('view')
>   #11 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_    Http))
>   #12 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(349): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
>   #13 app/Mage.php(640): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
>   #14 roa/index.php(80): Mage::run('en_roa', 'store')
>   #15 {main}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only file which is not from the core from the trace is this file:

app/code/local/Xprime/Category/controllers/CategoryController.php

First try disabling the Xprime_Category module and see if the error is still here.

If not, look into the viewAction function of this file.

You will probably find some code loading and rendering the layout.

Look for the module frontend layout xml file and look for the following code:

```
<block type="catalog/layer" />
```

That's the part of the code causing the issue.

Debugging will depend on the case and what this block is supposed to be used for.

Magento default layer block type is "catalog/layer_view".

I suggest you look into the base/default catalog.xml to see how a default install handles the layer code.

EDIT: Also check if the module has got its own layer block. If it does, I reckon it is the block supposed to be used instead of the original Magento block and it is not called properly.

Comment: Thanks @Digital Pianism, this is very detailed solution. And below is my findings.
1. By going to the config.xml of the Xprime_Category module, I can see it is using a customise layout file called xp_category.xml. see code snippet below,

        <layout>
            <updates>
                <xp_category module="Xprime_Category">
                    <file>xp_category.xml</file>
                </xp_category>
            </updates>
        </layout>
2. on xp_category.xml
            <block type="catalog/layer" name="catalog.leftnav" after="currency" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml"/>

Comment: Yes that's the issue, in the xp_category.xml file, change type="catalog/layer" to type="catalog/layer_view", that should fix the issue.

Comment: thanks so much again, I really appreciate your prompt help!